# for loop list countdown only shows up in the first one

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day, I am trying to duplicate my javascript countdowns along with pictures of cards on every loop. The problem is even when placed on the table inside the loop itself, the countdown only shows up in the first. I would like to know what am I missing.

There are other codes like adding cards in the webpage shown in the screenshot once clicked and the timer begins on each one, but the main issue is the loop not duplicating. when I add plain text on the table in place of , the plain texts show up on every card.

Thanks for any help.

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <h2 class="bold_font text-align-center">LIST OF CLAIMED CARDS</h2><br>
        <?php
          $i = 0;
          foreach($lstOrders as $rowOrder) {
        ?>
          <div class="col-md-4 spacer">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <?php
                $productid = $rowOrder['productid'];
                $rowProduct = $mcProduct->SelectObj_ProductId($db, $productid);
              ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <?php
                for($j = 0; $j < $rowProduct['packageid']; $j++) {
                  echo(' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift color-black"></span> ');
                }
              ?>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-12">
              <a href="info-detailed.php?i=<?php echo($rowProduct['productid']) ?>">
                <img src="../img/uploads/<?php echo($rowProduct['photosrc']) ?>" class="img-responsive clinic">
                <img src="../img/shadow-bottom.png" class="img-responsive">
              </a>

            </div>

            <table align="center">
              <tr>
                <td colspan="4">Reclaim This Coupon In:<hr></td>
              </tr>
              <tr align="center">
                <td id="c_countdown"></td>
              </tr>

            </table>
          </div>
        <?php
            $i = $i + 1;
            if($i >= 3) {
              echo('<div class="col-md-12"></div>');
              $i = 0;
            }
          } ?>

        <!-- Empty Col -->
        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        </div>
      </div> <!--row-->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 spacer">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT: (c_countdown)

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2019 15:37:25").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("c_countdown").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("c_countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

[image: output]

added TEST in table

[image: test]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use id as c_countdown. Id should be unique on webpage. `document.getElementById` only returns first element with that id. Try going with classes and then loop over elements.

You can use something like below in js code, but convert id attribute to class first in html.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.c_countdown').forEach(function(elem){
  elem.innerHTML = 'whatever you want to set here'
})
```

Comment: will the loop be inside the <td> in table?

Comment: Edited the answer, see what i am trying to convey.

Comment: thank you, using for eacha array and switching to class did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You forgot semicolon after echo statements here:

```
<a href="info-detailed.php?i=<?php echo($rowProduct['productid']); ?>">
    <img src="../img/uploads/<?php echo($rowProduct['photosrc']); ?>" class="img-responsive clinic">
    <img src="../img/shadow-bottom.png" class="img-responsive">
  </a>
```